# Why my regex doesn't capture the tracking expression in the string?

Tags: javascript

I try to parse the `ng-repeat` expressions from angularjs into a structured object using regex:

```
const ngRepeatExpressions = [
  "key, value in items track by key",
  "item in items",
  "item in items track by item.id"
];
```

I created this regex that extracts the variables and logs the expressions captured from the string:

```
const regex = /\s*(.+)\s+in\s+(.+)(?:\s+track\s+by\s+(.+))?/;
```

This regular expression has three capture groups:

1. The first capture group ((.+)) captures the variable that represents each item in the collection. If the ng-repeat expression uses the syntax key, value in items, this capture group will capture both the key and value variables.
2. The second capture group ((.+)) captures the collection that is being iterated over.
3. The third capture group ((.+)) captures the tracking expression, if present. If the track by clause is not present, this capture group will not be populated.

Here is the snippet:

```js
const ngRepeatExpressions = [
  'key, value in items track by key',
  'item in items',
  'item in items track by item.id',
];
const regex = /\s*(.+)\s+in\s+(.+)(?:\s+track\s+by\s+(.+))?/;
ngRepeatExpressions.forEach((expression) => {
  const [, variables, collection, trackingExpression] = expression.match(regex);
  console.log({variables, collection, trackingExpression});
});
```

But when I run this code, I see the `trackingExpression` variable is always undefined.

Why? The regex doesn't match the third capture group `((.+))`? How I need to change my regex so it matches the right `trackingExpression` and `collection`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the greedy `.+` in the second capture group, which will read all up to the end of the input string. Because the last part is optional, it doesn't need to backtrack.

A solution is to make that second capture group non-greedy (lazy), and require that the whole input is matched, using `^`  and `$` anchors:

```
const regex = /^\s*(.+)\s+in\s+(.+?)(?:\s+track\s+by\s+(.+))?$/;
```

Updated snippet:

```js
const ngRepeatExpressions = [
  'key, value in items track by key',
  'item in items',
  'item in items track by item.id',
];
const regex = /^\s*(.+)\s+in\s+(.+?)(?:\s+track\s+by\s+(.+))?$/;
ngRepeatExpressions.forEach((expression) => {
  const [, variables, collection, trackingExpression] = expression.match(regex);
  console.log({variables, collection, trackingExpression});
});
```